# find location of string in matrix

Tags: string, matlab, location, contains

I want to find the location of 'N' in a matrix. After this I want to replace that 'N' with the median of that vector in the matrix. I already used these codes for this but I get several errors.

```
%% put test data in matrix


k=1;
m=1;
n=3;
for j=1:99
    percentage2 = j/99
    mDataTest(m,1) = str2double(data{1}{j});
    mDataTest(m,2) = 0;

    for i = 3:50
        percentage1 = j/50       
        if(strcmp(data{i}{j},''))
            mDataTest(m,i) = 'N'; %give each "" the median value

        elseif(strcmp(data{i}{j},'NULL'))
            mDataTest(m,i) = 'N'; %give each "NULL" the median value

        else
            mDataTest(m,i) = str2double(data{i}{j}); %make matrix with data               
        end
    end
        m=m+1;
        n=3;
end

Index = find(contains(mDataTest,'N'));

for i = 1 :50
    vMedian=median(vDataTest(:,i));
end

mDataTest(Index)= vMedian(Index(2));
```

Here I use the 'contains' function but I get errors.
Is there someone that can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Without `data`, or at least an example input/output, we have no way to run your code and validate the results. Also please specify full error messages or why the results are wrong, not just "I get errors"

Comment: I think you can use something like `strrep` for this, but can't be sure until you provide an example input and output. Also, which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: *"the location of 'N' in a matrix"* What is 'N'? Also, does the matrix contain numerical values or characters? The question the way it posted is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit strange to me. Let me try to understand what it is you want to do.

So you start out with a 2D cell variable with text and you want to convert it to a numeric matrix. When cells are empty or contain 'NULL' you want them to have the median value of the row that they are in.

I would start with the conversion and make the empty and 'NULL' cells NaN. (Not a Number) Then find alle the nans and use `median` with the omitnan flag to replace the nans.

```
for j=1:99
    for i = 1:50
        if(strcmp(data{i}{j},'')||strcmp(data{i}{j},'NULL'))
            mDataTest(j,i) = nan; %replace with nan
        else
            mDataTest(j,i) = str2double(data{i}{j}); %convert to number
        end
    end
end

for j=1:99
    for i = 1:50
        if isnan(mDataTest(j,i))
            mDataTest(j,i) = median(mDataTest(j,:),'omitnan')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please don't try to clarify questions within an answer. When questions are unclear, make a comment to ask for more details! This way the answers are concise, detailed, and more useful to the asker and future readers. In contrast, your answer is 50% "this question isn't clear" and 50% "here's a guess of something you could consider"

Comment: I understand the question. It is in the first line of the post. It hasn't got the right terminology and the code that follows is a mess, but gives some idea of where it should go. The last line is just a function that was found but didn't work. She made an effort. It depends what you want with SO. If it is a platform for programmer help, then help them as good as you can, even if they are absolute beginners. If it is an encyclopedia with solutions to common problems, i think we should have only a few good programmers make opening posts.